# Im trying to Update my table in a database and i have no errors in my code but it still does not update?

Tags: python, sqlite

Hello i have small table which i want to be able to update this is what the table looks like before any updates:

```
RoomNumber       Available       Breakfast       Price       Booked          DateBooked          FullName
          1              1           0           49.0            0           NB               
          2              1           0           49.0            0           NB               
          3              1           0           49.0            0           NB               
          4              1           0           49.0            0           NB
```

and when i try to update the table once it has been executed it wont actually update and nothing gets changed this is the code that should update it:

```
print("#################### Database Updating ####################")
time.sleep(2)
with sqlite3.connect(DatabaseName) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    SQL = "UPDATE BOOKINGS SET Available = ?, Breakfast = ?, Price = ?, Booked = ?, DateBooked = ?, FullName = ? WHERE RoomNumber = ?"
    cursor.execute(SQL,data)
    db.commit()    
print(data)
print("#################### Database Updated ####################")
```

i don't even know where to look for the error and it is probably something small but i cant see anything, any help would be appreciated.

This is what data contains:

```
print("#################### Booking ####################")
RoomNumber = int(input("Please enter the Room number you want to book"))
SQLlibrary.CheckRoom(RoomNumber,DatabaseName)
Available = False
Breakfast = int(input("Would you like to have Breakfast included with your booking: 1 = yes, 0 = no"))

if Breakfast == 1:
    Breakfast = True
elif Breakfast == 0:
    Breakfast = False
else:
    print("Error")
    Booking()

Price = 49.00
Booked = True
Date = input("Please Input the date you want to book the room in this format: dd/mm")
FirstName = input("Please Enter your First name: ")
Surname = input("Please Enter your Surname: ")

FullName = (FirstName + "" + Surname)

data = (Available,Breakfast,Price,Booked,Date,RoomNumber,FullName)
SQLlibrary.UpdateDatabase(DatabaseName,data)
```

Comment: But what is the `data` field and what does it contain in this prepared statement?

Comment: i have editted the post to show where data originated from

Answer (score 0):

query:

```sql
UPDATE BOOKINGS SET Available = ?, ..., FullName = ? WHERE RoomNumber = ?
```

parameters:

```
data =             (Available,     ..., RoomNumber,        FullName)
```

This will work just fine, as long as you happen to have the same name as your room.